# html or javascript code help needed for alert command

Tags: javascript, html

I need help on the javascript code. I want to alert hello + (the word he/she entered in the first blank)+ (the word he/she entered in the second blank) when he/she clicked the button "submit information".

This is my html code

```
Please give yourself an adjective: <input type="text" name="adjective" id="id"><br>
Please input your name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
Please enter your gender<input type="text" name="gender" id="gender"><br>

<button onclick="Enter ()"> Submit Information</button>
```

I need javascript commands so these would work. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried a bit ? If yes Please show us. We will help you to make your code get working

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as:

```
Please give yourself an adjective: <input type="text" name="adjective" id="id">
Please input your name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

Please enter your gender<input type="text" name="gender" id="gender">

<button onclick="enter()"> Submit Information</button>
```

and in your javascript code:

```
<script>
var enter=function(){
alert('hello'+document.getElementById("name")+' '+ document.getElementById("gender") +'  '+document.getElementByName("adjective"));
}
</script>
```

you will get value you entered by using

```
document.getElementById("FormInputId_Here")
```

or

```
document.getElementByName("FormInputName_Here")
```

hope it will works for you..

Comment: Thank you so much, I am a beginner trying to create a basic quiz and this totally worked.

Answer (score 0):

To alert what you want to alert, you put them in an `alert()` function, since you're calling the function `Enter()` in your `onclick`, I have used this in my example as well

Here's one way to do what you want it to do:

**HTML**

```
Please give yourself an adjective: <input type="text" name="adjective" id="adjective"><br>
Please input your name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
Please enter your gender<input type="text" name="gender" id="gender"><br>

<button id="submit"> Submit Information</button>
```

**JS**

```
//Event listener for the button.
document.getElementById ("submit").addEventListener ("click", Enter, false);

function Enter() {
    alert("Hello " + document.getElementById('adjective').value + " " + document.getElementById('name').value  + " " + document.getElementById('gender').value);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var inputBox = $("#name");
var submitButton = $("#submit");

submitButton.click(function(){

    var getval = 'Hello '+ ($("#name").val()?$("#name").val():alert('please fill the text field'))
$('#text').text(getval);  
});
```

```html
Your Input: <input id="name" type="text" />
<button id="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>

<a id='text' ></a>
```